# Installing WiFi Drivers on MacBook Air

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.02 on my MacBook Air, unfortunately I have a problem with the wifi drivers. I checked the chip ID, it is BCM4360. I do not have a lan cable, so I was trying to download the drivers from another pc, but it seems it just does not work. Any help?
thanks

Comment: Can you tether your phone? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: thank you @chili555 !! i didn't think at that, i did a bluetooth tethering and was able to install the wifi drivers<3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I installed the Xubuntu **OEM** version which had no problem establishing a wifi connection. Don't know why.
After finished installation I used the icon on the desktop for 'distribution to users'. Dblclick it, restart and you can configure your installation as a custom version.